# i got error message after i install image_picker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, get, package, imagepicker

I installed image_picker after that I get error message when i start app
this is error log

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@40b49de9' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@5bca7644' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

what is this problem??
how can i solve this ~?

Comment: try running pub get, flutter clean and then running the app again

Answer (score 0):

The error happened when you were installing it
So first check the steps again :
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

If not work, try to recover AndroidManifest.xml again and follow the instructions